# Duplicates in SQL table: How to map the duplicates based on the rows value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like follwing (In microsoft sql server):

```
   [ID]
  ,[DamageCodeGroupID]
  ,[Name]
  ,[Swedish]
  ,[Finnish]
  ,[CreatedDate]
  ,[CreatedBy]
  ,[UpdatedDate]
  ,[UpdatedBy]
   [dbo].[DamageCode]
```

This table has many rows, and some of them have the same value. For example, ID 98 has the Swedish value 'Motor', so does ID number 286. How can I map this with some sort of sql query to see which rows have duplicates? (Based on the column Swedish)

To clarify, for example when doing:

```
SELECT * FROM DamageCode WHERE Swedish = 'motor'
```

The result is:

```
ID  DamageCodeGroupID   Name    Swedish Finnish
98         17           ENG01   Motor   Moottori
286        41                   Motor   Motor
```

So the result i want is some sort of script where i can map these older DamageCodes with the new ones. I have older Damage codes from ID 1 to 138. From ID 139 to 339 i have new codes. The output i want is to see how these are related, so for example if id 77 have the same name as id 133 or something similar.

Comment: Sample data, expected results, *and* (importantly) **your** attempt(s) will help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

…

```
select
   [ID]
  ,[DamageCodeGroupID]
  ,[Name]
  ,[Swedish]
  ,[Finnish]
  ,[CreatedDate]
  ,[CreatedBy]
  ,[UpdatedDate]
  ,[UpdatedBy]
from
(
select *, 
    -- If ID is unique 
    min(ID) over(partition by [Swedish]) as minID,
    max(ID) over(partition by [Swedish]) as maxID
    --count(*) over(partition by [Swedish]) as cnt
from [dbo].[DamageCode]
) as dc
where minID <> maxID -- cnt >= 2
order by [Swedish], [ID];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      WITH CTE AS
      (
        SELECT 1 AS ID,'MOTOR'AS VALUE
          UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 AS ID,'ENGINE'AS VALUE
          UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 AS ID,'MOTOR'AS VALUE
     )
    SELECT STRING_AGG(C.ID,',') AS XX ,C.VALUE  
    FROM CTE AS C
    GROUP BY C.VALUE
```

As you haven't provided  sample data and desired output,

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all the rows that have the same value for a particular column eg *swedish* you can do something like the following

```
select * from (
    select Swedish, Count(*) dupes
    from DamageCode 
    group by Swedish 
    having Count(*)>1
)d
join DamageCode dc on dc.Swedish = d.Swedish 
order by dc.Id
```